# Redirecting to Null in Inetrnet Explorer 11 (in some specific versions) after successfully login with AAD 2 Authentication in Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Redirecting to Null in Internet Explorer 11 (in some specific versions) after successfully login with AAD 2 Authentication in Angular 2.

In Chrome and other browsers working as expected.

From home page http://localhost:1234, will redirect to AAD 2 authentication login page. After successful login, it has to redirect to same home page i.e http://localhost:1234. But it is redirecting to http://localhost:1234/null.
But in other browsers, it is redirecting as expected. i.e http://localhost:1234/

Please help me on this issue.
I am using the below code.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { UserAgentApplication } from 'msalx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService 
{
  private config: Object = null;
  private Token: any;
  public getConfig() 
  {
    return this.config;
  }
  public getToken() 
  {
    return this.Token;
  }

  public clientID = this.con.getClientID();
  public graphAPIScopes = [this.con.getClientID()];
  //["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"];
  public redirectUri = location.origin

 constructor(private router: Router, private con: AppConfig) {
 }

 public clientApplication = new UserAgentApplication
 (
    this.clientID, null,(errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) => {
      // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
      if (tokenType == "id_token") {this.callTokenApi();
      localStorage.setItem('User', 
        JSON.stringify(this.clientApplication.getUser()));
        this.logMessage("User logged-in");
      } else {
        this.logMessage("Error during login:\n" + error);
      }
  });

  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    message: ""
  }

 logMessage(message: string) {
 }

 loginRedirect(sessionTimedOut: boolean) {
   if (sessionTimedOut) {
     this.clearUserInfoAndRedirectToLoginPage();
   }

   var GetState = this.clientApplication.isCallback(window.location.hash);
   if (!GetState) {
     if (!this.clientApplication.getUser()) {
       this.clearUserInfoAndRedirectToLoginPage();
     }
   }
}

clearUserInfoAndRedirectToLoginPage() {
  localStorage.setItem('User', null);
  localStorage.setItem('Token', null);
  this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(this.graphAPIScopes);
}

logout() {
  this.clientApplication.logout();
}

loginPopup() {
  this.clientApplication.loginPopup
  (this.graphAPIScopes).then ((idToken) => {
     this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(this.graphAPIScopes).
     then ((accessToken) => {
       var userName = this.clientApplication.getUser().name;
       this.logMessage("User '" + userName + "' logged-in");
     }, 
     (error) => {this.clientApplication.
       acquireTokenPopup(this.graphAPIScopes).
         then((accessToken) => {
           var userName = this.clientApplication.getUser().name;
           this.logMessage("User '" + userName + "' logged-in");
         }, (error) => {
           this.logMessage("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
         });
       })
     }, (error) => {
      this.logMessage("Error during login:\n" + error);
   });
 }
 callTokenApi() {
    this.clientApplication.
    acquireTokenSilent(this.graphAPIScopes).then   ((accessToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem('Token', accessToken);
        window.location.reload();
    }, (error) => {
    })
  }
  callApiWithAccessToken(accessToken: string) {
    accessToken;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be related to Internet Explorer running in `Protected Mode`.
According to Microsoft: "Msal.js is generated for JavaScript ES5 so that it can run in Internet Explorer."

To run your application locally, you'll need to disable this `Protected mode`. Follow the next steps:

1. Go to Internet Explorer Settings (the gear icon)
2. Choose Internet Options | Security, click on the Internet zone, and **uncheck "Enable Protected Mode (requires restarting Internet Explorer)"**. Internet Explorer will complain that your computer is no longer protected. Acknowledge

   [image]
3. Restart Internet explorer
4. Run and debug your application
5. When you are done, you can restore Internet explorer security settings by going to IE Settings | Internet Options | Security | Reset all zones to default level

---

**Just to take in count** (*Microsoft words*):

If you deploy your application to production (for instance in Azure Web apps), this will normally work fine, provided the end user has accepted popups. We tested it with Internet Explorer 11.

---

For a more detailed explanation you can visit [this MSAL Github link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/Using-msal.js-with-Internet-Explorer)